# How do I make a .htaccess file redirect any .org to its corresponding .com?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess file which right now looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).org$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foo.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Is it possible to put a variable in for the "foo.com" bit to just redirect to the same domain that was input, but with .com instead of .org?

Comment: Please elaborate on your requirement.. I am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation usually helps: [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> In addition to plain text, the Substitution string can include
>
> - back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern
> - ***back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern***
> - server-variables as in rule condition test-strings (%{VARNAME})
> - mapping-function calls (${mapname:key|default})